# Eclipse strings auto closing

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, quotation-marks

I did something bad to my Eclipse and have no idea how. 
What is worse, I have no idea how to fix it.

When I type quotation mark nothing appears in the editor. It waits for me to write anything, then written text appears in quotation marks.

Previously the behaviour was different. When I was typing quotation mark, both quotation marks were appearing and cursor was located between them.

I have another instance of Eclipse and the behaviour is how I want it.

Please help, however stupid it sounds :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Window->Preferences->Java->Typing** and choose what You want in "**Automatically close**" section.

Comment: I'm afraid it's already chosen. I mean, I checked this option. Actually, quotation marks close automatically but in different way.